# Ionic app build error

Tags: android, angularjs, jvm, ionic-framework

I Have installed everything required to run and build ionic app, it was running smoothly until now. Suddenly it has started giving all type of errors. I am new to ionic development so not able to understand this. Even tried google search, but was of no help till now.

I am getting below error, when trying to build application. It works perfectly with serve command in local browser. What could be the issue? Let me know if any more details are required from my side.

```
C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Solution\reli
ableapp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Solution\reliable
app
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp\platforms\android\cor
dova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Solution\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_71
Running: C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -
b C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daem
on=true
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostExcep
tion: downloads.gradle.org
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: downloads.gradle.org
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:178)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:996)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:850)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLCon
nection.java:2398)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1557)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp\pl
atforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp\platforms
\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Solution\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

C:\Users\Solution\reliableapp>ionic serve
Running live reload server: http://192.168.1.36:35729
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Running dev server: http://192.168.1.36:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $ q
```

Comment: Internet is properly working?

Comment: did you install the android sdk ??

Comment: @anas omar :Yes SDK is installed

Comment: @PareshGami Internet was not properly working, could that be an issue?